# Sqlalchemy - add columns to a query

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For example I am using the [chinook](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Home) database and I would like to convert the Name field into a slug. Slugify is a function from awesome-slugify.

Something like this in SQL

```
Select *, slugify(Name) as name_slug
from Artist
```

In sqlalchemy I have tried:

```
artist = Artist.query.add_columns(name_slug=slugify(Artist.Name)).all()
```

and

```
artist = Artist.query.add_columns(name_slug=[slugify(a.Name) for a in Artist.Name]).all()
```

I can generate a list of name slugs by doing to following in the terminal:

```
art = models.Artist.query.all()
name_slug = [slugify(a.Name) for a in art]
print(name_slug)
```

But I am not certain how to tie it all together.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't have slugify to test, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
artist = Artist.query.add_columns(slugify(Artist.Name).label("name_slug")).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with select statements:
stmt = sa.select(Artist.Age)

new_stmt = stmt.add_columns(Artist.Name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).