# Get SQLAlchemy properties from table object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I'm working in an API in python using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy. Recently I managed to match correctly the pydantics models that I'm using for request and response validation. However, the structure of my response is not the one that I want, and I found out that the problem is in the way SQLAlchemy returns the queries.

First, I was struggling to match the pydantic model that I defined before. After a while, I discover that in order to match my model, the property name required to match the name of the Table that I queried.
Here is how my models are right know defined:

```
class BasePost(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True
    
class ExtraPost(BasePost):
    creation_date: datetime.datetime
    last_update: datetime.datetime
    user_id: int
    user: ResponseUser

class ResponsePost(BaseModel):
    PostsTable: ExtraPost
    vote_count: int
```

The last model, ResponsePost, is the one that I used as my response_model parameter in my FastAPI endpoint. It's very easy to read, I just need a dict that has all the properties described in the first two models and and integer. But this is not the structure that I want. Before getting to this models, **I had this:**

```
class BasePost(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True 

class ResponsePost(BaseModel):
    creation_date: datetime.datetime
    last_update: datetime.datetime
    user_id: int
    user: ResponseUser
    vote_count: int
```

**Which is actually the structure that I desire.**
Now, going to the next part of the code, here is the endpoint that I wrote:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=List[ResponsePost])
def read_posts(user=Depends(get_user_from_token), db: Session = Depends(get_db), limit: int = INTEGER_LIMIT, offset: int = 0):
    try:
        post_query = db.query(PostsTable, func.count(VotesTable.post_id).label("vote_count")).\
            outerjoin(VotesTable, PostsTable.id == VotesTable.post_id).\
            group_by(PostsTable.id).\
            limit(limit).offset(offset).all()
        #for u in post_query:
        #    data = u[0]
        #    print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    return post_query
```

The code that is commented was useful to understand the type of variable I was getting from the query. It was at this point where I discover that the return object, this one: `<app.database.PostsTable object at 0x000001F11106C190>`includes the name of my table model, which was required in my pydantic model to get this result:

```
[
   {
        "PostsTable": {
            "title": "Updated post",
            "content": "Let's see",
            "published": true,
            "creation_date": "2023-11-19T11:44:41.386036-06:00",
            "last_update": "2023-11-19T11:44:41.386036-06:00",
            "user_id": 28,
            "user": {
                "email": "yo@gmail.com",
                "username": "yo"
            }
        },
        "vote_count": 2
   }
]
```

I don't want this structure. All the inner properties of the PostTable property should be outside, at the same level of the vote_count property, and the inner property user should be the only one that has as a value another object.

Comment: You MIGHT be able to do this usin SQLAlchemy's `add_columns`, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603584/sqlalchemy-add-columns-to-a-query). Something along the lines of `db.query(PostsTable).add_columns(func.count(VotesTable.post_id).label("vote_count"))`. Not at a computer, so haven't been able to try it, but try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to see your SQLAlchemy models..
But maybe it would be helpful for you.

**This example uses SQLAlchemy2.0 syntax.**

You can add to your SQLAlchemy model calculated field

```
class PostsTable(Base):
    ...
    vote_count: Mapped[int] = query_expression()
```

And when you query object, use something like this:

```
post_query_st = select(PostsTable).\
            outerjoin_from(PostsTable, VotesTable) \
            .group_by(PostsTable.id) \
            limit(limit).offset(offset).\
            options(
                with_expression(
                        PostsTable.vote_count,
                        func.count(VotesTable.post_id)
                )
            )

post_query = session.scalars(post_query_st).all()
```